# How to solve the issue response to preflight request doesnt pass access control check error?

Tags: node.js, angular, cors

I have a angular code in a VM, node code in another VM. I need to make an API call from this angular VM to node VM. I have included the cors module also. But still while making an API call, getting an error like

> "access to xmlhttprequest at 'http:IP1' from origin 'http:IP2' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesnt pass access control check: No 'Access control".

I have set header like this also,

```
app.use(function(req,res,next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',true);
    next();
}); 

app.use(cors());
```

But still I'm facing an error. Can anybody tell me how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set explicitly your localhost and add desired types of methods:

```
// Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
    // desired types of methods
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

UPDATE:

For example, your node server is hosted at `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. Then your Angular Application should be `http://127.0.0.1:4200`.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
npm install --save cors
```

and then:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: I have given my ip address like this 'http://10.00.00.00:8080'

Comment: I should give the node ip only knw in angular? yes  I have given & tested. But still Im facing this issue.. Could you please help ?

Comment: Again thanks for your effort, but I have given the ip of the angular in node like you have mentioned, still Im stuck with the same issue. We should only host angular & node application in the same VM? We cannot host in different VM's & make it work?

Comment: @sasi it looks like the problem lies in that you have two different virtual machines. If nodejs and Angular application would be at the same virtual machine, it should work. Can you put your Node and Angular applications on the same virtual machine?

Comment: yes it was working, but now they are asking me to run like this. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Yes I have already installed & used cors module, but still it didnt solve my issue..

Comment: @sasi try to write like that node server should be `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. and Angular Application should be `http://127.0.0.1:4200`. Just give a try. In addition do not forget edit these addresses in all your applications.